# How to generate dates between Start and End date specified using Division factor?

Tags: php, date

I have 2 php variables having dates as

```
$start_date = '01-12-2013';
$end_date = '01-12-2014';
```

And then I have a division factor as

```
$div_factor = 6;
```

And now what I want to do is generate 6 Dates (as defined in divison_factor) all with same number of days between each date.

I am going to use this to generate Installment dates for the specific period loans.

Comment: What should the output be for your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$start_date = strtotime("2013-12-01");
$end_date = strtotime("2014-12-01");
$datediff = $end_date - $start_date;
$number_of_days_between = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```

After that, just divise your `$number of days` by `$div_factor`, take your start_date, add the result and you have your first period ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$start_date = strtotime('01-12-2013');
    $end_date = strtotime('01-12-2014');
     $datediff = $end_date - $start_date;
     $diff =  floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
     $div_factor = 6;
     $inst = floor($diff/$div_factor);
     $inst_n = $inst*(60*60*24);
     for($i=0; $i<$div_factor; $i++)
     {
        $start_date =  $start_date+$inst_n;
        echo date('d-m-Y', $start_date);
        echo "<br>";
     }
```

this is done in my own way , you can change this as you wish.